# How to Print Out the Square Root of A Negative Number with i Displayed in C

Tags: c, complex-numbers, square-root

I am trying to figure out how to display the square root of a number if it happens to be negative (as it is entered by the user), and if so, display it correctly with the "i" displayed as well. When I do the normal `sqrt` function, the result is always something like -1.#IND. When I tried using the double complex variables, the positive numbers nor the negative numbers would come out clean.

Below is my code; the comments are what my goal is. The 4 num variables are entered by the user and can be any integer, positive or negative.

```
 //  Display the square root of each number.  Remember that the user can enter negative numbers and 
//  will need to find the negative root with the "i" displayed.
printf("\nThe square root of %d is %.4f", num1, sqrt(num1));
printf("\nThe square root of %d is %.4f", num2, sqrt(num2));
printf("\nThe square root of %d is %.4f", num3, sqrt(num3));
printf("\nThe square root of %d is %.4f", num4, sqrt(num4));
```

Comment: AFAIK, there's no short cut option.  You have to ensure you pass a non-negative value to `sqrt()`, and print the `i` if the raw value was negative.  Even if you use the complex arithmetic functions, I don't think there's a way to print complex values with [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) other than dissecting the real and imaginary parts and printing them separately.

Comment: "*When I tried using the double complex variables, the positive numbers nor the negative numbers would come out clean.*" -- What does this mean? That should work, but you haven't shown your code that attempted to do it, only the `sqrt()` call that clearly doesn't work.

Comment: [`sqrt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sqrt) works with a floating-point type and return the same floating-point type, so how can it accept a complex type? And it doesn't work with negative values because it doesn't return a complex type. Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with floating point you can use the built-in complex utilities, e.g.:

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double complex num = -4.0;
    double complex s = csqrt(num);

    printf("%.2f + %.2fi\n", creal(s), cimag(s));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
if ( num1 < 0 )
{
   printf("\nThe square root of %d is %.4fi", num1, sqrt(-num1));
}
else
{
   printf("\nThe square root of %d is %.4f", num1, sqrt(num1));
}
```

Comment: It's normally `3+4i` rather than `3+i4` for a full complex number, so `4i` rather than `i4` for a pure imaginary number, isn't it?  But that's nitpicking.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, your comment caught me by surprise. I remember (perhaps incorrectly) using `a + ` *i* `b` for most of my life. When look up in Wikipedia, they are using `a + b` *i*.

Comment: It's not impossible that it is a cultural thing — some cultures use one notation and others the other.  And it could be my memory at fault; I just looked at an antique 'Science Data Book' and it shows _Z = x + iy = r(cosθ + i sinθ)_.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Phew. For a moment I thought I was losing my mind :)

Comment: Nope: looks like it is me who is suffering from amnesia.  I checked two more maths books and they use the _x+iy_ notation.  It's a long time since I was last using this stuff…it was at least in another millennium, I think.  Wikipedia notes [both notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Notation) can be used — and I did a fair amount of working with _j_ instead of _i_ for the reasons stated.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  `3+4i` is the "normal/correct" convention. Non-constant multipliers, as in in `iy` or `i  sinθ`, are a different matter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler when using variables `x+iy` is used, but when using numbers , `3+4i` is used

Comment: @JimBalter: Ah; now that was a wrinkle that hadn't occurred to me.  Some parts of my memory may not be failing so badly after all, but since I wasn't able to articulate the distinction, maybe that's no real benefit.  When I look at one of the maths books harder, I see that it does use _x + iy_ for algebraic complex quantities (symbolic, if you prefer) but _3 + 4i_ for complex numbers.  Thank you!

Comment: @M.M: see my comment to Jim Balter — and thanks to you too.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
string root(int num) {
    return "" + sqrt(abs(num)) + (num < 0) ? "i":"";
}
```

Alternatively:

```
printf("\nThe square root of %d is %.4f%s", num1, sqrt(abs(num1)), (num1 < 0) ? "i":"");
```

Comment: The question is not tagged C++.

Comment: Sure, but this illustrates how to accomplish it in any language. OP can transcribe to C as he sees fit.

Comment: Using the `flag` variable seems odd: you could eliminate it and use `(num < 0) ? "i" : ""`.

Comment: OP said the inputted numbers are any integer. I considered not using `flag` but I wasn't sure in what order that line would work (if it `sqrt(abs())` before checking the ternary operator).